# How can I ignore text datatype length using script in sql?

Tags: java, sql-server, database-schema

I am trying to get ddl(create table) script of table using script which are given in following link.

[create script link](http://neelamsharma.s3.amazonaws.com/Create%20Table%20Script.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAINHDRCMKC5GUSNFA&Expires=1456467549&Signature=6UObP3Dip1ARqj8tjg3gePTm%2FgE%3D)

when I have pass table name and schema name in this script then it will give create table script .

eg. if existing table name is tablename and schema name is schemaname then it will give following result.

```
CREATE TABLE [schemaname ].[tablename ]
(
      [id] [nchar](10) NOT NULL
    , [name] [nchar](10) NOT NULL
    , [department] [nchar](10) NOT NULL
)
```

and when i execute that query then table is successfully created but
My Issue is that if i have text data type in my table then it will return following ddl.

```
   CREATE TABLE [UserOwner].[new_group_doc_history]
(
      [id] [int] NOT NULL
    , [older_values] [text](16) NULL
    , [new_values] [text](16) NULL
    , [modified_date] [datetime] NULL
    , [modified_by] [varchar](1) NULL
    , CONSTRAINT [PK_new_group_doc_history] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
)
```

And when I execute this query for create table then it will give following exception.

```
 Msg 2716, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column, parameter, or variable #2: Cannot specify a column width on data type text.
```

How can I resolve this issue.and please suggest me or any other datatype in sql server for which we can cannot give specify column width.

Comment: remove the `16` after `[text]`

Comment: Not asking about that what is the correct syntax of create table, Issue is that how to generate DDL for create table that has text data type without length .

Comment: @TejKiran please read thoroughly...

Comment: I am getting ddl of table by using script  which are mention in link so please suggest me if any modification in script which will give ddl of table without any width of text datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create your query like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE UserOwner.new_group_doc_history
    (
    id int NOT NULL,
    older_values text NULL,
    new_values text NULL,
    modified_date datetime NULL,
    modified_by varchar(1) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_new_group_doc_history PRIMARY KEY (id)
    )
```